# Checking for numeric values in columns of datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a utilities script that looks like this

```
public static bool CheckForNumbersInNumbersColumns(DataGridView datagridviewname)
    {
        bool numbersarenotpresent = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < datagridviewname.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (typeof (float) == datagridviewname.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.GetType() || typeof (float) == datagridviewname.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.GetType())
            {
                numbersarenotpresent = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                numbersarenotpresent = false;
            }
        }
        return numbersarenotpresent;
    }
```

It keeps returning false if I test it with any string value of just single letters in the cell, I would like it to return true and just stop running when that happens.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you want it to check if there are ANY numbers or if all values are numbers?

Comment: Any numbers... If there is anything other than a number (ie "f" or "steve") I would like it to return a true and then use that Boolean to initiate a messagebox and inform the user of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the value of each cell you want to check, and do a `TryParse`. If `TryParse` fails, it's an indication that the value was not a `float`.

More info on `TryParse` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xh24xh4(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public static bool CheckForNumbersInNumbersColumns(DataGridView datagridviewname)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < datagridviewname.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var value = datagridviewname.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        var value2 = datagridviewname.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
        float floatValue;
        float floatValue2;

        if (!Single.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out floatValue) || 
            !Single.TryParse(value2, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out floatValue2))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Nice! no problem. Please accept my answer (clicking the check mark) if you are satisfied with my explanation and response. :D

Comment: Can I pester you for one more question of a similar nature? Is it possible to do the same thing but check for colors in the cell instead of numbers or random strings?

Comment: what do you mean by colors? names of colors, or visually, the cell color?

Comment: the cells are supposed to be filled with colors in string form (ie "red", "blue" etc..).  I have a way for the user to load colors in the cells from the Microsoft library but would like a check to make sure its a proper color name instead of a random item that the user manually entered.

Comment: I think I have figured out my next question... Thank you for your help!